# Como centralizar o botão e dar uma margem dentro de uma div?

Tags: html, css

estou com dificuldade de centralizar o botão dentro da Div e dar um espaçamento. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

```
.btn{
background-color: var(--footer-azul-escuro);
padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
color: var(--primary-text-color);
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 1rem;
```

}

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgmWA.jpg)

Comment: esse .btn é a classe do botão !. para centralizar o botão, tem que especificar a propriedade na div para que o botão fique centralizado de acordo com o que foi passado na div, acho que deveria postar a parte da div correspondente ao botão...

Answer (score -3):

tentei entender o que você queria, fiz uma coisa simples que talvez te mostre um possível caminho.

Não posso colocar o link então vai o código todo.
index.html

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --background-color: #0e0e0e;
  --footer-azul-escuro: #0a1d4e;
  --footer-azul-escuro-hover: #3e70f0;
  --primary-text-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 38rem;
  background-color: rgb(225, 220, 220);
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}

.imagens {
  width: 95%;
  height: 22rem;
}

.title {
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  width: 95%;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.text {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: roboto;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 95%;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

.bottom {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.btn {
  background-color: var(--footer-azul-escuro);
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  color: var(--primary-text-color);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 40%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: var(--footer-azul-escuro-hover);
  border-color: var(--footer-azul-escuro-hover);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="card">
        <img class="imagens" src="https://www.miamiimportadosonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Delta-Children-Mason-the-Turtle-Lil-Play-Station-3-in-1-Activity-Walker-2.jpg" alt="imagem andador infantil com criança" />
        <div class="title">
          <h1>ANDADORES</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <P>Para crianças que pesam até 25 lbs. e até 30 \”Rotação de assento de 360 graus com trava de segurança 360 Grau de jogo mantém o bebê comprometido e entretido O ajuste de altura de três posições permite crescer com o bebê
          </P>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <button class="btn" type="button">Saiba mais</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="imagens" src="https://www.miamiimportadosonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Delta-Children-Mason-the-Turtle-Lil-Play-Station-3-in-1-Activity-Walker-2.jpg" alt="imagem andador infantil com criança" />
        <div class="title">
          <h1>ANDADORES</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <P>Para crianças que pesam até 25 lbs. e até 30 \”Rotação de assento de 360 graus com trava de segurança 360 Grau de jogo mantém o bebê comprometido e entretido O ajuste de altura de três posições permite crescer com o bebê
          </P>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <button class="btn" type="button">Saiba mais</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <img class="imagens" src="https://www.miamiimportadosonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Delta-Children-Mason-the-Turtle-Lil-Play-Station-3-in-1-Activity-Walker-2.jpg" alt="imagem andador infantil com criança" />
        <div class="title">
          <h1>ANDADORES</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
          <P>Para crianças que pesam até 25 lbs. e até 30 \”Rotação de assento de 360 graus com trava de segurança 360 Grau de jogo mantém o bebê comprometido e entretido O ajuste de altura de três posições permite crescer com o bebê
          </P>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
          <button class="btn" type="button">Saiba mais</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[clique aqui para ver a imagem de como ficou](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUqGm.png)